# How to use Direct2D with MinGW in Code::Blocks

Tags: mingw, direct2d

I red that GDI and GDI+ is now obsolete so I tried to use Direct2D. I have TDM MinGW64 4.7 up with Code::Blocks as IDE. It has the Direct2D headers in the pack - which is good as the WinAPI stuff isn't working with MinGW.

The first thing I came across is the headers missing the HwndRenderTargetParameters function. After looking into it in the WinAPI I realized it just fills a struct with simple data. I can do that manually - I thought. Did it and got a segmentation error from CreateHwndRenderTarget which is the place you would need to use that missing function. No wonder it's missing...

I searched the internet the whole day for anything that helps but there isn't anything MinGW releated can be find - regardless of Direct2D. So the question is: Is there anyone in this world who managed to make anything besides the basic "Hello world!" app with MinGW? I don't think so as there isn't any source code or tutorial on the entire internet that uses MinGW.

Prove me wrong please!

Seriously. Show me a very basic Direct2D example that will compile with MinGW in Code::Blocks for me. For example it draws a line across the window.

Comment: I can't even use just `#include <d2d1.h>` and an empty main function that returns 0, because in the file `dxgi.h` there are a bunch of things I assume to be Visual Studio macros, such as `__in` and `__out`. I tried blank-defining them and it sort of worked but didn't.